# Highlight key words in a given search text

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using following method to highlight the keywords in a given text.

```
private string HighlightSearchKeyWords(string searchKeyWord, string text)
        {
            Regex keywordExp = new Regex(@" ?, ?");
            var pattern = @"\b(" + keywordExp.Replace(Regex.Escape(searchKeyWord), @"|") + @")\b";
            Regex exp = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
            return exp.Replace(text, @"<span class=""search-highlight"">$0</span>");

        }
```

Sample Text: "What is .net Programming? Pl suggest few e-books"

Keyword: ".net"

When i try to search with key word ".net" .net is not getting highlighted in the given sample text.

When i try to search with key word "e-books" e-books is getting highlighted in the given sample text.

What would be the problem. Can anyone pl let me know where exactly do i need modify/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no word boundary before ".net" because `\b` only looks for a change between `\w` and `\W`, and both `.` and  (space) fall into the `\W` category, so there is no boundary between them.

One option is to simply look for "not a word-character" - i.e. not explicitly checking for the  boundary, only for the lack of a word character, using a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\w)
```

You could also check for anything that's not non-whitespace character, like so:

```
(?<!\S)
```

This one is a double-negative - it might seem more obvious to do `(?<=\s)` (or `(?<=\W)` for previous example), but these will prevent matches at the start of line from matching.

For an example of the difference between these two - the first one would match the .NET in `C#.NET` whilst the second one would not.

Since you're using .NET regex, you've fortunately got a fairly complete set of regex functionality - but it's worth point out that some other regex implementations don't support negative lookbehind - for those, you would need to use syntax like this:

```
(?<=\W|^)
(?<=\s|^)
```

(In all these cases, you want the equivalent lookahead on the other end.)

So, here's how those four variants would look in your pattern:

```
var pattern = @"(?<!\w)(" + keywordExp.Replace(Regex.Escape(searchKeyWord), @"|") + @")(?!\w)";
var pattern = @"(?<!\S)(" + keywordExp.Replace(Regex.Escape(searchKeyWord), @"|") + @")(?!\S)";
var pattern = @"(?<=\s|^)(" + keywordExp.Replace(Regex.Escape(searchKeyWord), @"|") + @")(?=\s|$)";
var pattern = @"(?<=\W|^)(" + keywordExp.Replace(Regex.Escape(searchKeyWord), @"|") + @")(?=\W|$)";
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. Pl suggest me what do i need to in this scenario.
Also i need to match the exact word.

Comment: Hi Chakri, I was just editing to add an actual example - that's done now. Let me know if any more details would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried the code suggested by u. if the the keyword .net is the at the starting of text then it is not highlighting.

Sample Text: .net programming fundamentals.

if .net is not at starting position then it is getting highlighted.

Pl help me.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have considered that! Simple solution is to add `|^` but I'll go update answer with more details.

Comment: Ok, hopefully this time the answer is clearer and works in all situations, but let me know if there's anything else I've missed.

Comment: I'm very thankful to u Peter... I'm very new to regular expressions. It helped me a lot. thanks for ur support